# Must a function have a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a compact metric space.

Suppose that $T: X \rightarrow X$ and for all $u \neq v \in X$,

$$ \rho(T(u),T(v)) \leq \rho(u,v) $$

Must $T$ have a fixed point?

My intuition is telling me that the answer is no, since the contraction mapping principle requires

$$ \rho(T(u),T(v)) \leq c\rho(u,v) $$

with $c \in (0,1)$ for there to be a unique fixed point.  However, I am struggling to come up with a counterexample.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: $X=\{-1,1\} $ and $T(x) = -x$?

Comment: Do you mean the finite set of just $-1$ and $1$ or the interval $[-1,1]$?  If it is the interval, then it has a fixed point at 0.

Comment: The finite set of course.

Comment: It's not  intuition, but sort of a meta-feeling: if they could have proved it for $c=1$, you would have learnt it as a theorem, so they're probably looking for a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

You may take the circle, $S^1={\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z}$ and an irrational rotation $T:\phi\mapsto \phi + \alpha$ with $\alpha\in {\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}$. It has no fixed point and no periodic orbits.